# Custom shortcut: which tool to use for binding key repetition to a script

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, xbindkeys

I'd like to bind key repetition of `ee` to correspond to input key `é` system wide.

To be more precise I'd like that typing `ee` within a time window of 500ms inserts a `é` character. Repetition outside of those 500ms would insert `ee`.

I know xbindkey let bind key to scripts but I didn't manage to find binding key repetition. Which tool / configuation would let me do that?

Comment: you could use xdotool.<br>
Check this on unix stack https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87839

Comment: @Y-Master I don't get how xdotool would help me for this. Correct me if I'm wrong but it's more an X automation tool directed by scripting

Comment: Although I suspect 'ee' is a common enough occurrence that the binding would be irksome- your choice of course !